# Three-body force in Greiner's electrodynamics

Tags: forces, many-body

In Greiner's book of classical electrodynamics there is an example formula of a three-body force between two charges.

> For *many-body forces* the force between two bodies 1 and 2 depends also on the positions of the other bodies $\mathbf{r}_3,\mathbf{r}_4,\dots$. For example, a three-body force would be
>   $$
> \mathbf{F}_{12}=kq_1q_2\frac{\mathbf{r}_1-\mathbf{r}_2}{\left|(\mathbf{r}_1-\mathbf{r}_2)\left(1+\frac{q_3^2}{q_1q_2}\frac{|\mathbf{r}_1-\mathbf{r}_2|}{|\mathbf{r}_s-\mathbf{r}_3|^3}\right)\right|^3}
> $$
>   Here, $\mathbf{r}_s$ is the center of gravity between $q_1$ and $q_2$. This three-body force would tend to a two-body force as $\mathbf{r}_3\to\infty$, as should be.

I know that this isn't the form of an electrical force, because the principle of superposition. Further, that form for a three-body force seems rather complicated and I'm not sure where it came from. How can this formula be obtained? Is it really applicable in some field of physics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks strongly like something that was chosen as a phenomenological example, without much consideration for physical forces. For instance, the units on the second term in the denominator don't currently make sense.

That said, three-body forces in general occur in various interesting places in nature, especially in nuclear physics (where they are required as an ingredient for many models) and atomic physics (where they are the mechanism behind Efimov states). See e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.4273 for a review of these concepts.